# rewrite_modで正規表現を用いて特定のCookieから値を取得し、HTTPリクエストヘッダへ設定したい

Tags: apache, 正規表現, cookie

■実現させたいこと
特定のCookie（User-Id）からユーザIDだけを抜き出し、変数として保持させ、HTTPリクエストヘッダへ設定したい。

■ソースコード

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} User-Id=([^;][^;]*);
RewriteRule .* - [env=X_UID: (ここへCookieから抽出した値を設定)]
RequestHeader append  User-Id %{X_UID}e
```

■試行内容
`env=X_UID:` の部分へ直接ユーザIDを入力したところ、HTTPリクエストヘッダへ出力されました。

■質問内容
Apache側でRewrite_modのデバッグログを設定したところ、取得したい「User-Id」を含めた全てのcookieを拾っている事が分かりました。
特定のcookieだけを指定し、値を抜き出したいのですが、cookieを指定した上で値を変数として取得することは出来るのでしょうか。

Comment: 参考: [Url rewrite in apache based on cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963104)